# Defining an ideal in the tensor algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, tensor-products

In the wikipedia article about [exterior algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Formal_definitions_and_algebraic_properties):

> The exterior algebra $Λ(V)$ over a vector space $V$ over a field  $K$ is defined as the Quotient algebra of the tensor algebra by the two-sided Ideal $I$ generated by all elements of the form $x \otimes x$ such that $x \in V$.

I want to show that $I$ is an ideal of $T(V)$ but i was confused about the elements of $I$, i mean what is exactly $I$ as a set and more particularly as a subset of $T(V)$.

Comment: You don't have to *show* $I$ is an ideal: by definition it is **the ideal** generated by elements of the form $x\otimes x$, for $x\in V$. Glad egreg's explanation clears up the rest: it's a pretty good explanation!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $S$ is a subset of a (non commutative) ring $R$, the ideal generated by $S$ consists of all elements of the form
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i s_i b_i
$$
where $n$ is an arbitrary integer, $a_i,b_i\in R$ and $s_i\in S$.

This set is obviously closed under addition (by construction) and contains $0$; it's also closed by left and right multiplication by elements of $R$, so it's an ideal. Any ideal containing $S$ as a subset must contain these elements, so this set is indeed the ideal generated by $S$.

In the particular case, you can think to $I$ as the set of elements in $T(V)$ of the form
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n A_i(x_i\otimes x_i)B_i
$$
where $x_i\in V$ and $A_i,B_i\in T(V)$. I'm afraid there's not much more that can be said, even in the finite dimensional case. What's important is that the relation
$$
x\wedge x=0
$$
is satisfied in $E(V)=T(V)/I$ (where $\wedge$ denotes the induced operation on the quotient ring) for all $x\in V$ because $x\otimes x\in I$ by definition.

This is just *one* particular construction of the exterior algebra: others are possible, but they will always give an isomorphic ring, because the exterior algebra satisfies a universal property. Therefore it's not really useful knowing what the elements of $I$ look like.

Comment: Thank you so much egreg !!

Comment: I'm learning this myself and that last paragraph addressed more than just the original question for me.

Comment: @BenjaminThoburn In the case of the exterior algebra over a finite dimensional vector space it's much more important to know what a basis looks like, in terms of a basis of the vector space: the products $e_{i_1}\wedge e_{i_2}\wedge\dots\wedge e_{i_k}$, with $i_1<i_2\dots<i_k$, for instance. This is *not* proved through the definition $\Lambda(V)=T(V)/I$. This definition can be handy in other cases, though.

Answer (score 7):

egreg says:

> I'm afraid there's not much more that can be said, even in the finite dimensional case

Actually a fairly precise characterization of the ideal generated by the tensors of the form $x \otimes x$ is possible. The ideal is spanned, as a *subspace*, by tensors of the form

$$x_1 \otimes \dots \otimes x_n \in V^{\otimes n}$$

where the vectors $\{ x_1, \dots x_n \}$ are linearly dependent! This is a nice exercise. It implies, among other things, that a wedge product $x_1 \wedge \dots \wedge x_n \in \wedge^n(V)$ in the exterior algebra vanishes iff the vectors $\{ x_1, \dots x_n \}$ are linearly dependent, which is a standard and useful feature of the exterior algebra.